# Abrir link em iframe depois de post PHP + JS

Tags: php, javascript

Fiz uma outra pergunta aqui no forum sobre outro assunto que me ajudou muito sobre isto porém o link abre em nova página.

O que eu gostaria é que ao clicar no submit abrisse dentro de um iframe dentro da página e se o campo não fosse preenchido recebesse uma mensagem (popup) informando que o campo não foi preenchido..

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['txt_url'])) {
$link = 'http://' . $_REQUEST['txt_url'] . '.datatix.com.br';
header('Location: ' . $link);
} 
?>

<div class="instancia">
<div class="content">
<img src="img/logo_datatix.jpg" height="32px">
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="txt_url" value="" placeholder="Digite sua Instância">
<input type="submit" value="Ok" name="ok "class="ok">
</form>
</div>
</div>

<div class="iframe">
<iframe id="conteudo_iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

Se possível não usar php seria muito melhor.

Seria mais ou menos o que está no código abaixo, porém o usuário não coloca o domínio inteiro apenas o subdomínio.

Exemplo: Ele coloca "teste" e da "OK" mas no iframe carregaria o link teste.dominio.com.br

```css
body{ padding:0; margin:0;}
.instancia{ background-color:#D3172F; color:#FFF; font-family:Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif; width:100%; position:fixed; border-bottom:#9B1022 2px solid !important;}
.instancia .content{ width:320px; margin:0 auto; display:table;}
.instancia img{ float: left;}
.instancia input{ height:30px; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; width:176px; border:0; float: left;}
.instancia .ok{ border:0; background-color:#9B1022; height:32px; width:32px; color:#FFF; float:left; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="instancia">
<div class="content">
<img src="img/logo.jpg" height="32px">
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="txt_url" value="" placeholder="Digite sua Instância">
<input type="submit" value="Ok" name="ok "class="ok">
</form>
</div>


</div>

<div class="iframe">
<iframe name="exemplo" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o atributo `target` do [*link*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) ou do [formulário](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target), com valor igual ao do atributo `name` do `<iframe>`

```html
<a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/" target="exemplo">pt.stackoverflow.com</a>
<form action="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/" target="exemplo">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<iframe name="exemplo"></iframe>
```

Observação: o `<iframe>` não vai terminar de carregar devido à restrições do SO, mas salvar o conteúdo em um arquivo HTML vai funcionar.

Comment: Mas como jogo o post do php nesse link?
Ele deve carregar assim que botar o subdominio no input e clicar em submit.

Comment: @RodrigoB.Silva modifiquei a resposta, o processo para formulário e link é o mesmo

Comment: <?php
  if (isset($_REQUEST['txt_url'])) {
  $link = 'http://' . $_REQUEST['txt_url'] . '.datatix.com.br';
  header('<script type="text/javascript">
 window.location.href =" ' . $link .'.datatix.com.br" ;
 </script>');
  } 
?>


Se eu fizer assim ele não carrega

Comment: editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a tag `targert` para identificar que você deseja que abra dentro do iframe, caso você deseja fazer alguma outra validação crie uma função no `onsubmit`

Comment: Mas como jogo o post do php nesse link?
Ele deve carregar assim que botar o subdominio no input e clicar em submit.

Comment: Você quer colocar a url obtida através do php como sendo a action do formulário ?

Comment: Isso mesmo, ou pode ser como um include.

Comment: <?php
  if (isset($_REQUEST['txt_url'])) {
  $link = 'http://' . $_REQUEST['txt_url'] . '.dominio.com.br';
  include ($link);
  } 
?>

Comment: Você tem o domínio ?
Você poderia gravar o domínio numa variável javascript e pedir para o usuário digitar o subdominio. O clique do botão dispararia um evento javascript que iria fazer toda a validação. `<form onsubmit="funcao()>` dentro da função você faria toda a sua validação